# django rest framework - what URL I should give for generic filters?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django with rest framework and I'm trying to use the generic filters backend.
My view looks like this:

```
class Agents(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializer.AgentSerializer
    model = serializer_class.Meta.model
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    queryset = models.Agent.objects.all()
    filter_fields = ('available', 'online', 'agency')
```

and I added the following URL:

```
url('^api/agents/$', api_views.Agents.as_view()),
```

now when I enter URLs like these:

```
api/agents/?online=False
api/agents/?available=True
```

it works and it return a correct list based on filters. however, when I try this:

```
api/agents/123/?online=False
```

I'm getting page not found.

reading [this doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-and-object-lookups) tells me that when I use generic filter it also works for returning single object, and they give the following URL as an example:
http://example.com/api/products/4675/?category=clothing&max_price=10.00

but I didn't understand if I should create my own URL specifically to get single object by id? or is it suppose to happen automatically? should I implement a get_queryset() that get parametrs from URL and either return all objects or specific object, and have two urls that use the same view?

The docs are not very clear about that.

thanks!

Comment: If you use [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/) then you can make use of [`DefaultRouter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) or [`SimpleRouter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) to automatically configure the urls for your list and detail endpoints. Otherwise you will have to provide these views and urlpatterns manually.

Comment: oh that's cool, thanks. and what about implementing get_queryset()? do I need to implement it and treat case with and without the parameter? or does it happen automatically too? what I'm missing is a full example of a generics.ListAPIView + get single object + filters to see how it all connect..

Comment: Ness, using the `DefaultRouter` or `SimpleRouter` should suffice.  You don't need to implement `get_queryset()` to get this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What the documentation meant is that if you have a DetailView and you configured the filters on that view, then you could have a 404 on an existing item if it doesn't match the filter criteria.

Note that you get the detail view for free if you're using `ViewSet`